# How to make dynamic custom textarea with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to make a dynamic form where the user can add more textarea and input elements when the user presses a button (named Tambah Penawaran).

The textarea element appends a bullet point upon pressing enter, which doesn't occur when the textarea element is dynamically appended to the form.

Please help me, Thank you.

Codepen:

[Example At Codepen](https://codepen.io/david-noya/pen/GRozBRb)

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="buatPenawaranContainer">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="buat-label col-sm-12 btn btn-secondary ">Penawaran</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="buat-label col-sm-3 btn btn-info " id="labelPenawaran1">Nama Penawaran</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9 buat-input-div">
          <input type="text" class="form-control buat-input" id="buatNamaPenawaran1" placeholder="Nama Penawaran" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="buat-label col-sm-12 btn btn-secondary" id="labelKeuntungan1">Keuntungan</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 buat-input-div div-keuntungan">
          <textarea id="keuntungan" class="form-control keuntungan todolist " name="todolist" rows="5" placeholder="Tekan Enter Untuk Setiap Keuntungan"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" w=100 tambah-keuntungan-container">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="tambahPenawaran">Tambah Penawaran</button>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
let tambahPenawaran = 1;
$("#tambahPenawaran").click(function () {
  tambahPenawaran++;
  $("#buatPenawaranContainer").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="buat-label col-sm-12 btn btn-secondary ">Penawaran '+tambahPenawaran+'</label></div><div class="form-group row"><label class="buat-label col-sm-3 btn btn-info " id="labelPenawaran'+tambahPenawaran+'">Nama Penawaran</label><div class="col-sm-9 buat-input-div"><input type="text" class="form-control buat-input" id="buatNamaPenawaran'+tambahPenawaran+'" placeholder="Nama Penawaran" required></div></div><div  class="form-group row"><label class="buat-label col-sm-12 btn btn-secondary" id="labelKeuntungan'+tambahPenawaran+'">Keuntungan</label></div><div class="form-group row" ><div class="col-sm-12 buat-input-div div-keuntungan"><textarea class="form-control keuntungan todolist" name="todolist" rows="5" placeholder="Tekan Enter Untuk Setiap Keuntungan"></textarea></div></div>');
});

$(".div-keuntungan").on('focus', '.keuntungan', function(e){
  if(e.target.value === ''){
      e.target.value +='• ';
  }
});

$(".div-keuntungan").on('keyup', '.keuntungan', function(e){
  let keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        e.target.value +='• ';
    }
    let txtval = document.getElementById('keuntungan').value;
    if(txtval.substr(txtval.length - 1) == '\n'){
     e.target.value = txtval.substring(0,txtval.length - 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is exact issue not clear ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 The bullet on the first textarea show, but at the textarea where the user added it, the bullet not show. I want the bullet show on all textarea.

Comment: not able to see which bullet you are mentioned in code pen not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attaching bullet events to the `textarea`, do it to the parent `div` *buatPenawaranContainer*. That way same functions will handle events for all new textareas you create.

```js
let tambahPenawaran = 1;
$("#tambahPenawaran").click(function() {
  tambahPenawaran++;
  $("#buatPenawaranContainer").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="buat-label col-sm-12 btn btn-secondary ">Penawaran ' + tambahPenawaran + '</label></div><div class="form-group row"><label class="buat-label col-sm-3 btn btn-info " id="labelPenawaran' + tambahPenawaran + '">Nama Penawaran</label><div class="col-sm-9 buat-input-div"><input type="text" class="form-control buat-input" id="buatNamaPenawaran' + tambahPenawaran + '" placeholder="Nama Penawaran" required></div></div><div  class="form-group row"><label class="buat-label col-sm-12 btn btn-secondary" id="labelKeuntungan' + tambahPenawaran + '">Keuntungan</label></div><div class="form-group row" ><div class="col-sm-12 buat-input-div div-keuntungan"><textarea class="form-control keuntungan todolist" name="todolist" rows="5" placeholder="Tekan Enter Untuk Setiap Keuntungan"></textarea></div></div>');
});

$("#buatPenawaranContainer").on('focus', '.keuntungan', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass("keuntungan")) return;
  if (e.target.value === '') {
    e.target.value += '• ';
  }
});

$("#buatPenawaranContainer").on('keyup', '.keuntungan', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass("keuntungan")) return;
  let keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode == '13') {
    e.target.value += '• ';
  }
  let txtval = document.getElementById('keuntungan').value;
  if (txtval.substr(txtval.length - 1) == '\n') {
    e.target.value = txtval.substring(0, txtval.length - 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="buatPenawaranContainer">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="buat-label col-sm-12 btn btn-secondary ">Penawaran</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="buat-label col-sm-3 btn btn-info " id="labelPenawaran1">Nama Penawaran</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9 buat-input-div">
        <input type="text" class="form-control buat-input" id="buatNamaPenawaran1" placeholder="Nama Penawaran" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="buat-label col-sm-12 btn btn-secondary" id="labelKeuntungan1">Keuntungan</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 buat-input-div div-keuntungan">
        <textarea id="keuntungan" class="form-control keuntungan todolist " name="todolist" rows="5" placeholder="Tekan Enter Untuk Setiap Keuntungan"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" w=100 tambah-keuntungan-container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="tambahPenawaran">Tambah Penawaran</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help sir.

Comment: Thank you sir it's work. I really appreaciate it. Can i ask you something sir?
What '' if (!$(e.target).hasClass("keuntungan")) return; '' do?

Comment: @DavidNoya it prevents the code to run unless what received the event was one of your textareas. If it does not have the class `keuntungan` then return and exit function. The idea is you might add more controls to `buatPenawaranContainer` in the future, and your code for bullets only makes sense for textareas with class keuntungan.

Answer (score 0):

You focus listener for your textarea bind when the page loads. The listener will not catch the boxes you generate after the page loads. To avoid this behavior, you have to bind the listener to the document.

`$(document).on('focus', '.div-keuntungan .keuntungan', function(e){...`

This will allow you to listen to dynamically generated elements.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation sir

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a bullet point on the first textarea on codepen. If you really want bullets to show for visual purposes then isn't it a matter of just wrapping the textarea being inserted in a li element? I did that and bullets appeared:

```
$("#buatPenawaranContainer").append('<li><div class="form-group row"><label class="buat-label col-sm-12 btn btn-secondary ">Penawaran '+tambahPenawaran+'</label></div><div class="form-group row"><label class="buat-label col-sm-3 btn btn-info " id="labelPenawaran'+tambahPenawaran+'">Nama Penawaran</label><div class="col-sm-9 buat-input-div"><input type="text" class="form-control buat-input" id="buatNamaPenawaran'+tambahPenawaran+'" placeholder="Nama Penawaran" required></div></div><div  class="form-group row"><label class="buat-label col-sm-12 btn btn-secondary" id="labelKeuntungan'+tambahPenawaran+'">Keuntungan</label></div><div class="form-group row" ><div class="col-sm-12 buat-input-div div-keuntungan"><textarea class="form-control keuntungan todolist" name="todolist" rows="5" placeholder="Tekan Enter Untuk Setiap Keuntungan"></textarea></div></div></li>');
```

You will have to style it to look decent: This could be a starting point for you:
CSS

```css
#buatPenawaranContainer {
  padding: 10px;
}
#buatPenawaranContainer li{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: There is a bullet point when you click it. I need the bullet for seperate each sentence not just for visual purposes. Thank you for the comment